# How to check if Laravel Cache Lock is already locked

Tags: php, laravel, locking

**TLDR:** How to check if a Laravel Atomic Lock is already locked without having to lock it and inspect the return value of the `$lock->get()` call?

I have multiple Laravel commands that execute through the scheduler. One command is not scheduled and if it is running no other command should run. Therefore I introduced the [Atomic Cache Locks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#atomic-locks) from Laravel like this:

```php
private function checkSetupRunning(){
    $lock = Cache::store('locks')->getStore()->lock(
        self::RUNNING_KEY, // name for the lock
        owner: self::class
    );

    if ($lock->get(fn() => null) === false) {
        throw new SetupRunningException();
    }
}
```

This does work as expected, howewer when running multiple of these commands in parallel it seems like sometimes the lock is already aquired through the `checkSetupRunning` function of another command and therefore fails, even though the setup-command is not running.

So I would need a way to check if the lock is already aquired, without needing to lock the lock. I've checked the documentation and some of the code but was not able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way we have found

```php
 public static function getCacheLockOwner(string $key): string|false
 {
        return Cache::lockConnection()->client()->get(Cache::getPrefix().$key);
 }
```

It will return the lock owner (a string) if it exists, or false.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about this question. I have actually solved the problem pretty much identical as you :)